# Is it possible to use Page View Controller with Single View Controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I have `one View Controller` that handles `three views`, to do this i use `horizontal scroll view` of size (320 * 3 ). But if i want to use `Page Controller` now, how can i do it?. I have read that page controller will require `different View controllers` for itself to show those dots at the bottom, but right now i have `one View controller` and `three different views`. So is it possible to use Page Controller in my case.? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello there [this is an excellent tutorial](http://iosmadesimple.blogspot.in/2013/01/page-control-for-switching-between-views.html) using single ViewController for pagecontroller like feel

Comment: The link is expired, any updated link or answer available?

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same using scrollview only. just create three pages in scrollview. set its width to 320. and apply paging to scrollview. and in the bottom of scrollview use pageControl.
and use the following code to get the current page rank.

```
CGFloat pageWidth = scrlViewMain.frame.size.width;
    int page = (int)floor((scrlViewMain.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
    pageControlMain.currentPage = page;
// note: write the above code in scrollViewDidScroll method.
```

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Add a scrollview in your view controller. Add your 3 views as subView of scroll view. Position will be:

1. 1st view rect will be (0,0,320,480) //for screen size of (320,480)
2. 2nd view rect will be (320,0,320,480)
3. 3rd view rect will be (640,0,320,480)

Enable the paging of scrollview.

[image]

Let me know if this helps.. :)